# Nginx location proxypass doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I have a rails app with nginx + puma

I add these locations to my nginx site config:

```
  location = /helloworld.html {
    ssi on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass https://liveblog.dday.it/api/upload-raw/blogs/5c20ff839a954a50bec0a4b9/index.html;
  }

  location = /helloworld2.html {
    root html;
  }
```

I cannot understand why the last one is working, the first one redirect to my rails app.

**edit**

I understand the issue, the problem is that my main domain is dday.it

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name dday.it www.dday.it;
  return 301 https://www.dday.it$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name dday.it;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dday.it/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dday.it/privkey.pem;
  server_name www.dday.it;
  root /var/apps/dday.it/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_dday.it;
}
```

If I proxy pass to a different domain, like example.com, everything works. The "loop" happen is I proxypass to liveblog.dday.it

Answer (score -1):

first location is redirect the request to a new link, second location says for request to yoursite/helloworld2.html to looks inside local path html.

if you try to do like this:

```
location = /helloworld2.html {
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html
}
```

and put in the path this index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTM>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>I'm Hello World 2</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <center><h1>Hello World 2</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

that should display to you the content of index.html

Comment: The second block works. It's the first, with the proxy directives that doesn't.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I discover the issue, I add an edit. But I don't know how to solve...